# PDO Auto-aliasing when fetching?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following two tables:

**foo:**

```
ID     NUMBER(38)
DATA   VARCHAR2(10)
```

**bar:**

```
ID     NUMBER(38)
FOO_ID NUMBER(38)
DATA   VARCHAR2(10)
```

When using `PDO` to issue the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo f INNER JOIN bar b ON (f.id = b.foo_id)
```

Is there any way to get back *all* of the columns from the join in some kind of auto-aliased format (e.g. "FOO.ID", "FOO.DATA", "BAR.ID", etc.) so that I don't need to specify and alias every single column in the query?

I've read all of the documentation on the various [fetch modes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), and experimented with most of the [flags/options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php), but still can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

**Update:**

*Using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, the columns from `foo` seem to be overwritten by the columns from `bar`:*

```
array(3) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["DATA"]=>
  string(5) "bar 1"
  ["FOO_ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

*Using `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, the columns from both `foo` and `bar` appear, in order, but without any way to identify which columns came from which tables, except by knowing the number of columns in each table and exact order of those columns (error prone):*

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "foo 1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "bar 1"
}
```

*Using `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, we seemingly run into the same problems as `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and `PDO::FETCH_NUM` combined, and create a horribly unintelligible result set:*

```
array(8) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["DATA"]=>
  string(5) "bar 1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "foo 1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["FOO_ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "bar 1"
}
```

*IDEALLY, the result set should look similar to this:*

```
array(5) {
  ["FOO.ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["FOO.DATA"]=>
  string(5) "foo 1"
  ["BAR.ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["BAR.FOO_ID"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["BAR.DATA"]=>
  string(5) "bar 1"
}
```

Comment: You can always refer a column with it's qualified name `tableName.columnName`, if this is, what you meant (it's not a alias though).

Comment: It's sort of a good habit to get into explicitly listing columns in select queries instead of `SELECT *` anyway...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Unfortunately, I don't have that luxury in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no way to do this behind the curtains.  Explicit aliasing is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, at least you need to do:

```
SELECT f.*, b.* FROM foo f INNER JOIN bar b ON (f.id = b.foo_id)
```

Comment: This does not seem to give the desired result in PDO, though.  None of the keys when you fetch are labeled `f.id` or similar.  In fact, it seems to actually overwrite the non-numeric keys and produce really strange result sets.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT f.ID as fID, f.DATA as fDATA, b.*, FROM foo f INNER JOIN bar b ON (f.id = b.foo_id)
```

the idea is to change only the conflicting attributes so that there is no more conflict.